C# Unity - High Precision Timer using TimerQueueTimer
I'm trying to execute a C# callback every 10ms with a 1ms accuracy if possible. For the moment in my project I'm simply using a spin loop and stopwatch and I did achieve the desired result with <1ms variation but it consume 100% of a cpu core which isn't ideal. I'm looking for solution to avoid that and I came across some thread talking about the C method CreateTimerQueueTimer, more info here.
I made the following script below to test that in Unity but for some reason I cannot get a timer with less than 15ms interval. The accuracy looks very good, but I need to get below 15ms. I tried to use the timeBeginPeriod as it was suggested here but it didn't change a things. Am I doing something wrong in my code or this isn't the right way to do it ?
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
public static class TestHighResTimer {

    private static readonly string debug_id = "[HighRes Timer]";
    private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw;
    private static int count = 0;
    private static IntPtr timer = IntPtr.Zero;

    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        //Setup some callback so that we don't crash when editing code, reloading domain ect...
        AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload += Destroy;
        EditorApplication.update += StartTimer;
        EditorApplication.update += EditorUpdate;
        Debug.Log($"{debug_id} Init");
    }

    private static void Destroy()
    {
        Debug.Log($"{debug_id} Destroy");
        EditorApplication.update -= EditorUpdate;
    }

    private static void StartTimer()
    {
        EditorApplication.update -= StartTimer;

        Debug.Log($"{debug_id} Start");

        //Prepare the stopwatch and count to measure the callback interval
        sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        count = 0;

        timeBeginPeriod(1); //It is supposed to improved accuracy of timer event but I didn't notice a change...
        CreateTimerQueueTimer(out timer, IntPtr.Zero, TimerCallback, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 10, 0); //Start a timer to fire the callback every 10ms
    }

    private static void EditorUpdate()
    {
        //We limit the test at 1000 iterations otherwise it will run indefinitely
        if(count > 1000)
        {
            DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr.Zero, timer, IntPtr.Zero); //Clear the timer
            timeEndPeriod(1);
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    private static void TimerCallback(IntPtr p, bool b)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{debug_id} Tick : {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} [ms]");
        sw.Restart();
        count++;
    }

    public delegate void WaitOrTimerDelegate(IntPtr lpParameter, bool TimerOrWaitFired);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateTimerQueueTimer(out IntPtr phNewTimer, IntPtr TimerQueue, WaitOrTimerDelegate Callback, 
                                                 IntPtr Parameter, uint DueTime, uint Period, uint Flags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr TimerQueue, IntPtr Timer, IntPtr CompletionEvent);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern uint timeBeginPeriod(int msec);
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern uint timeEndPeriod(int msec);
}


Window's default clock resolution is 15.625ms (1/64s), which is why you're seeing the ~15ms minimum. See Increase timer resolution (high resolution) on Windows without NtSetTimerResolution or How to setup timer resolution to 0.5 ms?

I used to increase the frame rate by decreasing the interval time. Instead, I now increase the number of iterations within the same interval; with a corresponding time slice. I can increase the frame rate until the "work" exceeds the time available.

@ipodtouch0218 The first link provided seems to offer a solution using the Real-Time Work Queue API from windows, but it is very difficult to find example / tutorial on how to use it. And the documentation is a bit obscure... I'll play around with it to see what I can do.

Actually, I think you should first consider whether you need such functionality in the Unity3d project, as this is an unusual task for a game.
